# Angular 2+: orderBy pipe minification

Tags: angular

I have read the warnings about not using pipes for ordering/sorting. I understand the issues with impure pipes, but not the issue with minification.

In the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe) and as mentioned in other posts, they mention the issue of aggressive minification and pipes. I don't fully understand what the issue is with  minification. I did set up a custom orderBy pipe and all works fine. Looking at the minified bundles all appears normal.

1. Can someone please elaborate for me what they warn us about in regards to minification?
2. If I am to move away from a pipe, they mention to use a service, but how does that look when I need to re-use and with an rxjs stream of data? Using combineLatest or something?

Answer (score 1):

I assume minification problems have to do with mangling of variable names, because if you are referencing a variable in html as `foo` and that gets mangled during minification to `f`, the component may still reference `foo` whereas the pipe might be looking for `f`.

But more importantly, sorting and such on pipes will be very inefficient, because every time the component re-renders, the pipe will also be called again, and if you have long, complex lists, you can imagine how this can quickly get out of hand.

Comment: If you work with immutable data structures, a pure *orderBy* pipe would have a decent performance.

Comment: Thanks Lansana, as I look at the minified bundle from CLI I don't see the variables changed. And as for my case I am ok with pure pipe which is not called all the time. I'm trying to get to the bottom of this minification warning from Angular team...